# how to show table in editing mode in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, subclass

in app i have custom tableview which subclass of uiviewcontroller & i want to show editing in tableview when i show self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
when i clicked on it the tableview doesn't show red minus sign.
where i was wrong & what i do for come out from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self.editButtonItem; only : in case your class is a subclass of UITableViewController sub class .

In case of UIViewController sub class self.editBarButtonItem does not work.

In this case you can use

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(edit:)] autorelease];

and in edit method set editing

-(void)edit:(id)sender
{
  myTable.editing=YES;
}